# How to speedup the delay of the pressed signal of QPushButton compared to KeyPress event in Qt/ PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt-GUI with a function to move an object that is connected both via the `pressed`-signal to a QPushButton and via a `QEvent.KeyPress`-event to a key from the keyboard. However, I notice a serious lag in the object movement after clicking the PushButton, which is not the case if I press the specified key on the keyboard.

1. **Can you explain why the execution of the same function is slower if triggered by the PushButton compared to the key-event?**
2. **Is there a way to make the execution faster/ the lag slower for the QPushButton?**

Here is an abstract of the relevant code:

```py
class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self, control: 'Controler'):
    super(GUI, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi("ressources/interface.ui", self)

    # Defining the QPushButton and connecting the signal with the function
    self.button_left = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, "button_bbox_left")
    self.button_left.pressed.connect(lambda: self.translate_along_x(left=True))

  # Handling key_press_event with eventFilter
  def eventFilter(self, event_object, event):
    if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress) and (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A):
      self.translate_along_x(left=True)

  # The function that moves the object
  def translate_along_x(self, distance=0.05, left=False):
    if left:
      distance *= -1
    move_object(distance)
```

One difference between the two function calls is that for the QPushButton I have to use a lambda-function due to the parameter. But the lag remains if I set it without the lambda-function.

**Update**

As @eyllanesc suggested I tried to create a *minimal reproducible example*. You find it below. There I could not measure a significant difference. So (although it is much simpler) it might be more like PyQt is not executing all clicks if I click the button repeatedly a lot of times.

So is there an option to make the button handle many fast clicks better?

MRE:

```py
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        button = QPushButton("Click me")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        self.start = None
        
        button.pressed.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.do_sth()
        
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.do_sth()
        
    def do_sth(self):
        print("Reacted to signal/ event!")
        print("Took %s seconds!" % str(time.time()-self.start))
        
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @musicamante I read about that and as showed above also use the `pressed.connect` signal. Or did I understand you wrongly?

Comment: @rayon sorry, I misread your code. How are you "measuring" that difference, and how much delay are you noticing?

Comment: Well it's actually hard to measure, since I can only start the timer with the signal fired. But it's seems more like the signal is arriving later.

Comment: @rayon The error is acceptable since I see few microseconds of difference, is it that appreciable for your application? You should also note that if you do 2 clicks you will see that the times are not the same since the print is not similar since it is accessing different variables (different memory spaces)

Comment: @eyllanesc You're right that lag is neglectable. I updated my question and the problem seems more that PyQt is not handling all (fast, repeated) button clicks, while it does that smoothly for fast key pressing. So all in all the user interaction is much smoother with key than with click control. Might that be due to catching of double click or the like?
(I also timed the event & signal execution in my app and also that is the same, so I assume it is about the firing of the signal.)

Comment: I did not observe that none is faster than the other but that sometimes one is more time consuming and in other cases not. I think you are worrying about things that are out of our hands (or you plan to modify the implementation of Qt/C++ or SIP/PyQt5)

Comment: If a few microseconds difference are a significant issue for you then I'm afraid that Python was a not so good choice to implement your application. Furthermore, Qt is known for a lot of things but not for its extra-ordinary speed. So, even the choice of Qt might be questionable. Though, if Qt is used right (and carefully excluded from the performance critical paths of your application), it shouldn't be an issue. (We do Visual Sim. with a Qt GUI and an OpenGL 3d visualization, and in most cases we achieve a satisfying performance or, at least, Qt is not responsible for not achieving it.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your comment. I am aware of the speed limitations of PyQt and that's why I only compare the relative speed between keyPress and buttonPress. So it's probably more about how multiple fast clicks on PushButtons are handled. Do you have any ideas on how to make that faster, i.e. in a non-blocking fashion?

Comment: I must admit I don't have. I consider the GUI as non-performance critical in general. The human perception level is usual about a 1/10th second. Compared to this, even "slow" Qt is usually sufficiently fast enough. I should've mentioned as well that we write most of our stuff in C++ while we use Python exclusively as a kind of embedded macro language to implement custom extensions for the interactive model setup. And, of course, I know that First Person Shooter gamers are much more critical about reaction times of the GUI but they are beyond our target group (for my luck). ;-)

Comment: _PyQt is not executing all clicks if I click the button repeatedly a lot of times._ Would it be an option to hold down the push button for repeated clicks? I just remembered the [autoRepeat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop). (There are also [autoRepeatDelay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatDelay-prop) and [autoRepeatInterval](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeatInterval-prop) available.)